# What kind of templating engines besides jinja can be used for latex?

Tags: pythontex

I have started to create automated reports in latex using jinja, also looked at pylatex as well and was wondering what other templating engines are available for programatically generating latex documents.

I know that there are a decent amount of other projects such as [latex build](https://github.com/pappasam/latexbuild), but wanted to get a better sense of what tools are available. Would pandoc be a good option?

Comment: Pandoc can convert Markdown to LaTeX or directly to PDF (using LaTeX), but if you want to change the defaults you end up needing to know quite a bit of LaTeX. For quick documents it's useful though.

Comment: You can also convert XML to LaTeX using XSLT (or import XML using ConTeXt or several other solutions).

Comment: latex files are just text so people generate them with all kinds of tools, perl, python, xslt, ......